# Typescript type assertion for "dynamic" record

Tags: typescript

I seem to be missing something, but the `| AlertDynamic` seems to break my typing suggestion

```js
type Alert = {
  type: string
  variant: 'danger' | 'warning' | 'success' | 'info'
  message: string
}

type AlertDynamic = (arg: string) => Alert

export const alertTypeAuthentication: Record<string, Alert | AlertDynamic> = {
  incorrectPassword: {
    type: 'Incorrect password',
    variant: 'danger',
    message: 'Adgangskode er forkert.',
  },
  passwordCreated: (email: string) => ({
    type: 'Password created',
    variant: 'success',
    message: `We sendt a message to ${email}`,
  }),
} as const
```

When just using `Record<string, Alert >` I don't see a type error for `alertTypeAuthentication.incorrectPassword.message`

Comment: To be clear, you're getting a type error for `alertTypeAuthentication.incorrectPassword.message` when you're using `Record<string, Alert | AlertDynamic>`, which is what your question is about?

Comment: Typescript won't know that incorrectPassword is of type Alert, it will know it's one of the given types. It doesn't matter that you used `as const` since the Record type is on the variable

Comment: getting `Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Alert | AlertDynamic'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'AlertDynamic'.` when using `Record<string, Alert | AlertDynamic>` and typing `alertTypeAuthentication.incorrectPassword.message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript won't know that incorrectPassword is of type Alert, it will know it's either `Alert` or `AlertDynamic`. It doesn't matter that you used `as const` since the `Record` type is on the variable `alertTypeAuthentication`.

You can solve this by letting typescript infer the type itself, like this:

```
export const alertTypeAuthentication = {
  incorrectPassword: {
    type: 'Incorrect password',
    variant: 'danger',
    message: 'Adgangskode er forkert.',
  },
  passwordCreated: (email: string) => ({
    type: 'Password created',
    variant: 'success',
    message: `We sendt a message to ${email}`,
  }),
}
```

Or create a wrapper type like this:

```
type Alert = {
  type: string
  variant: 'danger' | 'warning' | 'success' | 'info'
  message: string
}

type AlertDynamic = (arg: string) => Alert

type AlertTypes = {
  incorrectPassword: Alert
  passwordCreated: AlertDynamic
}

export const alertTypeAuthentication: AlertTypes = {
  incorrectPassword: {
    type: 'Incorrect password',
    variant: 'danger',
    message: 'Adgangskode er forkert.',
  },
  passwordCreated: (email: string) => ({
    type: 'Password created',
    variant: 'success',
    message: `We sendt a message to ${email}`,
  }),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`alertTypeAuthentication` is a `Record<string, Alert | AlertDynamic>`, which means that the compiler doesn't know that `alertTypeAuthentication.incorrectPassword`is an `Alert` or `alertTypeAuthentication.passwordCreated` is an `AlertDynamic`, only that they can be either an `Alert` or `AlertDynamic`.

[Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) allow you to write custom type guarding logic. Since `Alert` is an object type and `AlertDynamic` is a function type, we can narrow between the types using those properties on some argument of `Alert | AlertDynamic`:

```
type Alert = {
  type: string
  variant: 'danger' | 'warning' | 'success' | 'info'
  message: string
}

type AlertDynamic = (arg: string) => Alert

function isAlert(a: Alert | AlertDynamic): a is Alert {
  return typeof a === 'object';
}

function isAlertDynamic(a: Alert | AlertDynamic): a is AlertDynamic {
  return typeof a === 'function';
}

const alertTypeAuthentication: Record<string, Alert | AlertDynamic> = {
  incorrectPassword: {
    type: 'Incorrect password',
    variant: 'danger',
    message: 'Adgangskode er forkert.',
  },
  passwordCreated: (email: string) => ({
    type: 'Password created',
    variant: 'success',
    message: `We sendt a message to ${email}`,
  }),
};

if (isAlert(alertTypeAuthentication.incorrectPassword)) {
  console.log(alertTypeAuthentication.incorrectPassword.type);
}

if (isAlertDynamic(alertTypeAuthentication.passwordCreated)) {
  console.log(alertTypeAuthentication.passwordCreated("foo"));
}
```

Check it out on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNhATsKBeKBvAsAKClUSALigGdhEBLAOwHNd8A3AQyueuBIHIATd2pFygAfKFwDurajVpDRXUgFcAxsoilScsTQBmAey4MoAW3WlmAkuSp1cAX1y5C0eEmAARENWbHKytFAAFKy0VhQyAJRoAHywCMiOODqK1MrAlHrUUJSkrsjBJHkookWe3r7KESTM2aRxbphGiBDAiohZzno6UDWofWJ6AEYAVhBpXADc9onJqemZtaVePn4F9cgi6x7LFVU9tVtlK-7YeFDNre0E4BBd+33oXLNpGdST0zi4ypnkPfHAABUbjBFMAABYQDh+ZjzagkABKYz0iB4AB5rDIADRbTZLcp+WLoU74GjfRDNNIABWYGnEyJ4JGJ+GuxDEAElUsiKSgwDTSHSUVxMUYmKxKOxOGI+HRBMKzvhTBoLBBuDAeLR+KQANZ6HjQJBQfSILVuAB0QqMdjl+F5tPpAGFmjCIAyghBjMxKHAwjZaFFULFAkz8M5uNS7SioMoncAXRb5VAWGwONwlKozPHmSYzMqSAADADq0FIkJ4KBqivMAgIeigABIMO7PXA7HnrVA7BE5XYpp8cJRuoEckVgv8gZAQeDIellDDXqbSVyxsBw-z6REokzvtRSHoEKa4HpaKO3OOIJOIVDZ7CF5zycvVwKeKbnBFew4+wOgsP-kcKifkDPC9p2hG9bTXFFHQgZ0eA3Rozm3Xd90PY9mDHYFQUvGc50yU1wKfKCYMCAAifQ9GIjd31wIA).

Comment: Type predicates is also a cool way to solve this for sure :)